# MemSql GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE,GEOGRAPHY_CONTAINS,GEOGRAPHY_WITHIN_DISTANCE is not working and returning null

Tags: singlestore

> It is not returning any figure, It is returning null.

```
SELECT round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE("GEOGRAPHY_POINT(-97.741890, 30.219940)", "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))"),0) FROM DUAL;

SELECT GEOGRAPHY_WITHIN_DISTANCE("GEOGRAPHY_POINT(96.843820, 32.926290)","POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))",1000) from dual;
```

can anyone please help to make this memsql Geospatial Function work

Comment: Aren't your `POINT`s specified wrong? Shouldn't the two values be space separated and `long lat`, not `lat,long`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes its lon,lat...corrected it but still it showing null. dont think its space separated for ref : https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/geography_point/

Comment: `GEOGRAPHY_POINT` *isn't* WKT - In WKT, it's just [`POINT`](https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/geospatial-guide/#geospatial-types)

Comment: It worked. Thank you :-)

Comment: I am maintaining lat lon and polygon(Datatype: GEOGRAPHY) in a table. Can i maintain POINT datatype in a table ? like i was maintaining for GEOGRAPHY_POINT so that i can compute the distance for multiple records? 
E:G Create Table (...
 LAT DECIMAL(10,7) NOT NULL,
  LON DECIMAL(10,7) NOT NULL,
VEHICLE_GEO_POINT as geography_point(lon, lat) persisted geographypoint,
  index(VEHICLE_GEO_POINT),
...
)

Comment: Yes, you can define a point from lat long coordinates that way. I'm not sure what your question is. With VEHICLE_GEO_POINT defined like that, you can compute the distance with GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE(VEHICLE_GEO_POINT, other_geography_thing)

Comment: Yes it works,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer above, the GEOGRAPHY_POINT syntax  should not be inside a string. You can either define the point within a string in WKT syntax `POINT(long lat)`, or using the GEOGRAPHY_POINT syntax (but not in a string).

So for your first query that wasn't working:

```
memsql> SELECT round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE("GEOGRAPHY_POINT(-97.741890, 30.219940)", "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))"),0) FROM DUAL;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE("GEOGRAPHY_POINT(-97.741890, 30.219940)", "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.086939 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.39 sec)

memsql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                            |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1862 | You have an error in your WKT syntax at position 0 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can correctly write it as either of these two:

```
memsql> SELECT round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE("POINT(-97.741890 30.219940)", "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))"),0) FROM DUAL;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE("POINT(-97.741890 30.219940)", "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))" |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           291334 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.31 sec)

memsql> SELECT round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE(GEOGRAPHY_POINT(-97.741890, 30.219940), "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123))"),0) FROM DUAL;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| round(GEOGRAPHY_DISTANCE(GEOGRAPHY_POINT(-97.741890, 30.219940), "POLYGON ((-97.11090087890626 33.08693925905123,-96.52862548828126 33.063924198120645,-96.56158447265626 32.80343616698929,-97.06970214843751 32.778037985363675,-97.11090087890626 33.08693925 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           291334 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.54 sec)
```